# Compare with "be exposed to" and " be exposure".. give examples please

Tags: meaning, word-meaning, word-difference

What is the meaning difference between "be exposed to" and "be exposure". Especially I can't interpret the meaning of "exposed to". When and how should I use it?

I saw a sentence about it recently. It was:

> It just opened up a new world to me. I'd never **been exposed to** other cultures, and that trip gave me my first taste of the world outside my country

Which word(s) can be used instead of *exposed to*?

Comment: I've never heard *be exposure* used before. I suspect it's ungrammatical. (On the other hand, *be exposed to* is grammatical and common.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Be exposed to** means that someone or something is brought into contact with something else, often with the implication that the contact will cause some kind of change. For example "I want my children to **be exposed to** a wide variety of cultures and lifestyles", or "Workers at Chernobyl were expected to **be exposed to** high radiation levels".

**Exposure** is the state of being exposed or revealed. "Children benefit from **exposure** to a wide variety of cultures and lifestyles", or "Your product will benefit from wide **exposure** to the public".

**Be exposure** cannot be used in place of **be exposed to** or simple **exposure**. The only way I can think of it being used would be something like "The only thing I would have to fear would **be exposure**".

Alternatives for **Exposed to** could be:

- Experience - *Kids benefit from **experience** with a wide variety of cultures and lifestyles*
- Subject - *Workers at Chernobyl were **subject** to high radiation levels*
- Reveal - *I'm afraid the journalists will **reveal** my identity*

Answer (score 1):

To **expose** someone or something **to** a thing is to put the person or that something in a position where the thing can influence them or affect them in some way.

> Do not expose the biscuits to air or they will go stale.
>
> When paint is exposed to the sun the color fades.
>
> A child exposed to music at an early age may become a musician.
>
> We you travel to a foreign land, you are exposed to a new culture.

"ex" means "out" and "pose" is related to "position". The meaning is to put something out (where it can be affected in some way).

This locution is a passive construction. The transitive verb is **expose**.

> Expose the wound to air so it may heal better. <sup>active voice</sup>
>
> The wound was exposed to air so it would heal better.<sup>passive voice</sup>

Therefore, to find a substitute for "be exposed to" it must also have this passive meaning. Being exposed to a thing is something that *happens to* the thing which has been exposed.

You might say

> We were shown another culture.
>
> I had never been shown another culture until I went overseas.

When you **open yourself to** other cultures, that is something you are doing on your own behalf, so it is not a perfect substitute for "be exposed to", yet it has a similar meaning of allowing yourself to be influenced.